# Can't set data to a queryRun object

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I'm creating a report and have problem with using this line of code:

```
this.queryRun().setCursor(tmpTable);
```

**tempTable** filled with records before and I just want to pass the data to the queryRun object. But I got a *runtime* error that an **argument have a wrong type**.

What am I doing wrong? 
Is there any other way to copy data from table to queryRun?

Comment: Could you describe the structure of the query? Is `tempTable` the first data source of the query?

Comment: @FH-Inway I already found my mistake, but I'm pretty sure you had a right guess :) see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ehh, my bad. 
The datasource of Query in the Report was empty. 
That's why I got an error. But That's really wierd that error is not some kind of **NullReference** but just **wrong argument type** which is not clear.

So solution is just init the queryRun by yourself:

```
Query                   q;
QueryRun                qr;

q = new Query();
q.addDataSource(TableNum(TempTable));

qr = new QueryRun(q);
qr.setCursor(tempTable); // Works fine!
```